# Is UIKit still using OpenGL rendering in 2020?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, uikit

I want to figure out how UIkit renders, but when I searched, I only found some articles, claiming that UIkit uses OpenGL to command GPU. Apple has given up support for OpenGL long ago, I guess these articles may be out of date (Shouldn't it be something like Metal?).

If I want to learn about this, what official documents should I read, and what keywords to search for in search engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIKit is built upon Core Animation. Every view has a `CALayer` and that is what's on the screen. Core Animation now uses Metal and CoreGraphics, according to [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is referenced by the [documentation page for the Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore).

[image]